# Merge every member of cv::Mat A with cv::Mat B in order to create a cv::Mat C with [a(x,y),b(x,y)] as a result

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, matrix

I am trying to generate a cv::Mat C from two other matrices in order to get a third matrix that is made by 2-D points generated by combining 1-D points of matrices A and B.

My problem is that everything I tried only concatenates the matrices, and does not really merge each point with another, which would result in a 3-D matrix of 2-D points.

Does anyone can help me with this issue?

Thank you so much.

Just to be more clear:

What I have is `A = [(0, 1, 2),(3, 4, 5)]` and `B=[(5, 4, 3),(2, 1, 0)]` and I would like to create

```
 C = {[(0,5), (1,4), (2,3)],
      [(3,2), (4,1), (5,0)]}.
```

Thank you

Comment: I do not think such API in opencv exists that would do this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a custom type matrix. See [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#datatype)

Basically, you need to create a specialization of `DataType` class that handles points (pairs of data).

Or you can use the given matrices of `std::complex<double>` instead of integers as an ugly shortcut. Example code in the documentation:

```
Mat B = Mat_<std::complex<double> >(3, 3);
```

However, this solution might not be the real solution to your general problem. Google XY problem.

Comment: I would not call using std::complex as an "ugly shortcut". It is recommended to use already defined structures, although using std::pair<int,int> would be more suitable in this case. And even more suitable - cv::vec2b

Comment: You were right. I did not need to create this matrix. My problem is that I have already calibrated my camera, but I need to upload the camera matrix and the distortion coefficients to it in order to get the images calibrated in real time. But I still do not know how to do that. At least now I understood that I was asking for Y while my real problem is X.